# AngularJs call to Rest Api POST Not Found

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest

I'm practicing AngularJs with Restful webservices. I'm using Spring 4.2.4
For me fetching of all records and deletion of records are working. But if I want to insert some data then it throws error of 404 Not Found.

Error is

```
 POST http://localhost:8080/admin/saveCategory 404 (Not Found)
```

This is my AngularJs Service and Controller

Service.js

```
App.factory('categoryService',['$http','$q',function($http,$q){
return {
    fetchAllCategory: function(){
        return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/admin/getCategories').then(
            function(response){
                console.log(response.data)
                return response.data;

            }, function(errResponse){
                console.error('Error while fetching users');
                return $q.reject(errResponse);
            }
        );
    },

    addCategory: function(category){
        if(category == null){
            console.log("Category is null");
            return $q.reject("Category is null");
        }else{
            return $http.post('http://localhost:8080/admin/saveCategory',category).then(
                function(response){
                    return response.data;

                }, function(errResponse){
                    return $q.reject(errResponse);
                }
            );
        }

    },

    deleteCategory: function(categoryName){
        return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/admin/deleteCategory/'+categoryName).then(
            function(response){
                return response.data;

            }, function(errResponse){
                return $q.reject(errResponse);
            }
        );
    }
};
}]);
```

Controller.js

```
App.controller('categoryController',['$scope','categoryService', function($scope,categoryService){
var self=this;
 $scope.category={catId:null,catName:''};
self.categories=[];

self.getAllCategories=function(){
    categoryService.fetchAllCategory().then(
        function(categories){
            self.categories=categories;
        },
        function(errResponse){
            console.error('Error while fetching Categories');
        }
    );
}

self.addCategory= function(){
    categoryService.addCategory($scope.category).then(
        self.getAllCategories,
        self.reset(),
        function(errResponse){
            console.error('Error while Adding Category.');
        }
    );
}

self.updateCategory = function(categoryName){
    for(var i = 0; i < self.categories.length; i++){
        if(self.categories[i].catName == categoryName) {
            $scope.category.catId = self.categories[i].catId;
            $scope.category.catName = self.categories[i].catName;
            break;
        }
    }
};

self.getAllCategories();

self.submit= function(){
    self.addCategory(self.category);
    self.reset();
}

self.deleteCategoryCtr=function(categoryName){
    categoryService.deleteCategory(categoryName).then(
        self.getAllCategories,
        function(errResponse){
            console.error('Error while deleting User.');
        }
    );
}

self.reset = function(){
    $scope.category={catId:null,catName:''};

};
}]);
```

My Rest Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/admin")
public class CategoryController {

@Autowired
private CategoryService categoryService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/saveCategory",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Void> saveCategory(@RequestBody CategoryHelper categoryHelper){

    if(categoryHelper.getCatId() == 0){
        categoryService.addCategory(convertToCategory(categoryHelper));
    }else{
        categoryService.updateCategory(convertToCategory(categoryHelper));
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/deleteCategory/{catName}")
public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteCategory(@PathVariable("catName") String catName){
    categoryService.deleteCategory(catName);
    return  new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/getCategories")
public ResponseEntity<List<Category>> getAllCategories() {

    List<Category> categories = categoryService.getCategories();
    if (categories == null || categories.isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Category>>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Category>>(categories,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}



private Category convertToCategory(CategoryHelper categoryHelper) {
    Category category = new Category();
    category.setCatId(categoryHelper.getCatId());
    category.setCatName(categoryHelper.getCatName());
    return category;
}
}
```

I also have wrote controller method for insertion like below it's also not working.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveCategory",method = RequestMethod.POST,  consumes = "application/json")
 public ResponseEntity<Void> saveCategory(@RequestBody String jsonObject){
     ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
     try {
        categoryHelper =  objectMapper.readValue(categoryJson,CategoryHelper.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(categoryHelper.getCatId() == 0){
        categoryService.addCategory(convertToCategory(categoryHelper));
    }else{
        categoryService.updateCategory(convertToCategory(categoryHelper));
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Category Helper Class

```
public class CategoryHelper{

private int catId;
private String catName;

public int getCatId() {
    return catId;
}

public void setCatId(int catId) {
    this.catId = catId;
}

public String getCatName() {
    return catName;
}

public void setCatName(String catName) {
    this.catName = catName;
}
}
```

In Rest Web Service Client it's like postman this is what it shows

```
Request:

POST http://localhost:8080/admin/saveCategory
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
{"catId":null,"catName":"Black Berry"}
```

Response (Summery)

```
404, Not Found
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Mon, 14 Mar 2016 07:33:23 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Language: en
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 992
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Expires: 0

Time taken (in milliseconds): 38
```

Comment: Can you try your API using REST client like Postman in chrome? Not sure it is Angular issues or your server. I have the feeling it is something with server

Comment: I have applied every possible solutions to server side controller But still it gives same error.

Comment: So, are you sure your server side is working and this issue is from the font-end side?

Comment: From server side i'm getting the data even deletion of record works. Only if it do not works it's on sending data to server.

Comment: The url is not hitting the method mapped in server for it.

Comment: I have updated my question...

Comment: try this on java method header: `  @RequestMapping(value = "/saveCategory",method = RequestMethod.POST,  produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
     public ResponseEntity<Void> saveCategory(@RequestBody String catId, String catName){ .... } `

Comment: @Saahon  same error POST http://localhost:8080/admin/saveCategory 404 (Not Found)

Comment: then change annotation @RestController to @Controller and add before method name @ResponseBody, it turns:    `@Controller @RequestMapping(value="/admin") public class CategoryController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/saveCategory", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,  method = RequestMethod.POST,  )
 public 
@ResponseBody
ResponseEntity<Void> saveCategory(@RequestBody String catId, String catName){ ... }`   and then restart the project

Comment: Done this one also same error.

Comment: The error occurs in angularjs here   xhr.send(isUndefined(post) ? null : post);  angular.js:10765